# How do I remove this shower fixture?

Tags: plumbing, shower

I'm a little desperate here.  When we moved into this home, we inherited this shower fixture.  Now it's leaking.  But, I can't figure out how to remove it!?

[image]
I've tried to back it all the way off and looked for a set screw on the bottom.  I can't find any manuals online for this part.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the screw in the center is missing (the hole in the center of the piece that says "off").  I would try pulling on that center part to remove it (the screw that was there probably was to hold it in place but now that it is gone it *should* come off... easier said than done).  You will probably need to pull fairly hard or even use a screw driver to slowly pry it off (especially if it has been on for a long time it might take some work to get it off).  Then once that center piece comes off you should see the other screws that are holding the rest of the unit on.

Comment: or use a drill to just drill out the rusted-in-to-oblivion screw head.

Comment: @longneck - you would need to replace the whole thing though.

Comment: After you drill out the old rusted center screw, try a wheel puller if you have one.

Comment: @ChrisF - good point, i was under the impression the OP wanted to replace the whole thing. a stripped screw removal bit might be more appropriate. or with a bit of careful drilling, the shaft of the screw might be exposed enough that it could be removed with a pair of plyers.

Comment: That was it.  I hadn't wanted to pull so hard on it.  But, with the encouragement above, I went for it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a faucet handle puller. These are available at almost any hardware store for under $15.

[image]

You stick the middle pin into the hole in the center of the faucet, and adjust the side-pincers to grab the handle from beneath. Then you turn the handle to gently, directly pull the faucet handle off.